# Can a router be part of multiple HSRP groups?

Tags: router, hsrp, fhrp

Because we configure HSRP on interface level, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course that is not only possible, but it is usually the case. Each VLAN will have at least one (possibly more) HSRP groups, even on the same interface.

It used to be a common practice to set up an HSRP group for odd addresses to one primary router, and a different HSRP group on the same interface for the even addresses that uses the other router as its primary. That is not really used much any more because that doesn't work well with layer-3 switches, where you want the STP root bridge to be the same as the HSRP primary to avoid sub-optimal frame delivery.